# How to backup/sync saved game folders between multiple computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, backup, script

I'm trying to basically sync some saved game files (in this case from Red alert 3) over 2 computers.

So what I would like to happen is when I start my game, a script or batch file searches a network folder (T:\saves) and copies the latest version of the saved game folder to the local machine (c:\users\NAME\Red Alert\Saves).

Once the game/process ends, I would like the script to copy the latest local version to the network location.

I would also like the script to play nicley if the network location isn't available if possible.

Is this kind of thing possible using a batch file or autohotkey perhaps? I thought perhaps even dropbox could prove useful?

All of my computers are running Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the easiest way of doing this, by using dropbox and symbolic links:

**How to sync backed up games using dropbox**

1. Install [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTY4NTAwMDQ5) on machines you want to use save games with, make sure it is all up and running ok
2. **Move** your saved game folder (eg. c:\users\username\game name\saves) into your dropbox folder (Dropbox\Saved games\game name\saves)
3. Create a symbolic link from the original save game folder location to your new dropbox saved game location - make sure that the symbolic link folder name is the same as the original folder name

Basically what this will do is create a shortcut, so that when your game looks for its saved game folder, it is actually being redirected to a different location (in this case, the dropbox folder)

Here is a simple app for creating symbolic links: [symlinker](http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/)

[image]

**Please note:** symbolic links only work in Vista and Windows 7 - not XP

Here is my dropbox referral code for anyone wanting some extra space on dropbox (we both get an extra 250mb free if you use this link): [Get dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTY4NTAwMDQ5)

Comment: Symlinks are specific to file system, not to OS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: Another nice feature of Dropbox is that it will sync directly if the computers are on the same network.  Saving you some round-trip time.

Comment: @Ionut Staicu - "most Unix-like  operating systems such as Mac OS X, and also Windows operating systems such as Windows Vista, Windows 7 and to some degree in Windows 2000 and Windows XP."

symbolic links don't work great in XP

@scott - dropbox is indeed awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the freeware Allwaysync: http://allwaysync.com.  It can be set up to sync on a schedule, on hardware events or on file changes.  It's very stable, reliable and runs quietly in the background.